# babel-plugin-transform-remove-console isn't working

Tags: javascript, package.json

I'm trying to remove console.log from my js project. I use webpack for build.
package.json

```
 {
    ...other package.json
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "serve": "webpack-dev-server --mode development"
  },
      "babel": {
        "presets": [
          [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
              "targets": {
                "esmodules": true
              }
            }
          ]
        ],
        "plugins": [
          [
            "transform-remove-console",
            {
              "exclude": [
                "error",
                "warn"
              ]
            }
          ]
        ]
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    ...other rules
      }
    }
```

I run npm run build but still have console logs in my console.
webpack

```
module.exports = {
...other
  mode: 'production',

};
```

what is wrong?